# Remove jars from JDK in order to show code completion only for packages that i actually use?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, java

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and would like to take advantage of the built in code completion etc. However, it's overloaded with thousands of objects that exist in the JDK, but I have no idea what they are and probably will never use. Is it possible to go into Project Structure - SDK's and remove most of the jar files listed there under SDK 1.7 classpath ? The reason I want to do this is to not have code completion etc include those objects. If yes, which ones would I have to keep (i.e. rt.jar, etc?) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file -> settings

type auto import in search field

look for "exclude from import and completion" box and add here the classes that you don't want to see